# Laravel unique validation, only if value is different & without id

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I am trying to update the data and to do this I am using a method patch on my form.

**Update Validation Request**

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'question' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    Rule::unique('faqs_questions','question'),
    'max:30',
],
```

If there are no changes in my question it gives me an error:

> The question has already been taken.

**`dd($this->toArray())` on validation request gets me below output:**

```
array:9 [▼
    "_method" => "PATCH"
    "_token" => "LLqlQfMpzSdyAInVOaqs5lqBMbEvNT9eMDU9ZZxJ"
    "my_name_TOApMPqqwwBasdts9bLa" => null
    "valid_from" => "eyJpdiI6IkJ2TUpZV29ZV0Qzasdasdaasgst5345wtgrtyegq4yhq4qhgqgMDU1"
    "question" => "Question B"
    "answer" => "Answer B"
]
```

I tried using `Rule::unique('faqs_questions','question')->ignore($this->question),` on my request file but I think it needs id which we don't have in any inputs. Is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following which uses a `where` clause to say we want to check the `question` is not already in the table.

```
$validator = Validator::make(['question' => $request->question], [
    'question' => [ 
        'required', 
        'string',
        Rule::unique('faq_questions')->where('question', '!=', $request->question),
        'max:30'
    ]
]);
```

You can change the field it checks against to be whatever you want, hopefully the above gives you the general idea.

Then you can check if validation was successful or unsuccessful:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   // error
}
```

Comment: I accept this solution but can we do the same in request because my validations are being done in the update validation request file and I want to avoid using validations in controller

Comment: Yes, you can use the `Rule::unique(...)` in `FormRequest`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example of the validation in laravel 8,

```
public function edit($id, Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id, 'id'),
            'fname' => 'required',
            'sname' => 'required',
            'lname' => 'required',
        ]);
        $user = User::find($id);
        $input = $request->all();
        $results = array_filter($input);
        $user->fill($results)->save();
        return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'success' => 'Your Info Has been Saved']);
    }
```

If I understood your question well

Answer (score 0):

What about putting it into a hidden input?

If whatever you're sending via `question` is unique, you can also use something like this: `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->question, 'slug')`

Comment: I thought about it am using slug as a parameter already which is unique.
Let's suppose I turn `'question B'` to `'question A'` and submit form then `$this->question` will pick input as `'question A'` instead of `'question B'`. We need to make sure that the slug is being passed to request I suppose so that we can call an ID to make it unique and ignore that particular ID. Any clue how can we achieve this task?

Comment: If you change the slug, you change the slug and therefor, it can no longer be used as an identifier. If you intend to change the slug now and then, I wouldn't go for that solution. In that case, the hidden input is safer. But if you want to do the slug solution, make sure to add `slug` to `$guarded`.

Comment: As you can see the output doesn't have a slug parameter available in it how will we be able to fetch slugs in it?

Comment: Which output? You don't show the model structure. So that was my best guess. You have to know what is possible with your project setup.